# Label gets cut off after text got changed in the background

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I am currently facing the problem that my label gets cut off after I changed my text in the background.
After testing and trying to figure out why this happens, I noticed something interesting. The problem/bug only occurs when using `HorizontalOptions=Center` on my label (also CenterAndExpand). For testing purposes I changed the horizontalOptions to Fill/Start/End/etc. and it worked fine. The text did not get cut off.

Unfortunately I cannot find any solution, nor workaround to this problem.

Maybe some of you have faced an similar issue in the past and can help me.

**Following attempts did not work:**

In the past padding made some problems with the text. So I tried to change it to margin. Did not work

I moved the horizontalOptions into the code behind and added `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextOrientation))` in the OnBindingPropertyChanged. Did not work

Setting a WidthRequest disables horizontalOptions complete. So this does not work either

Setting a MinimumWidthRequest does not work

In our app you can answer questions. When your answer is correct the app shows you this:

[image: Correct answered]

If you answer the next question wrong, the label looks like this:

[image: Second question wrong answered]

My StackLayout with the two labels from the screenshots look like this:

```xml
<!-- Feedback -->
<StackLayout Spacing="0"
             Margin="{ Binding FeedbackStackLayoutPadding, Source={x:Reference Root} }"
             IsVisible="{ Binding HasFeedback }"
             HorizontalOptions="{ OnIdiom Default=Fill, Tablet=Center }">
    <Label HorizontalOptions="{ OnIdiom Default=Fill, Tablet=Center }"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="{ DynamicResource LayoutDirectionHorizontalTextAlignment }"
           Text="{ Binding FeedbackInfoText, Source={x:Reference Root} }"
           TextColor="{ Binding FeedbackInfoTextColor, Source={x:Reference Root} }"
           FontFamily="{ StaticResource AppBoldFontFamily }"
           FontSize="16" />
    <Label HorizontalOptions="{ OnIdiom Default=Fill, Tablet=Center }"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="{ DynamicResource LayoutDirectionHorizontalTextAlignment }"
           Text="{ grial:Translate FL6_Question_CorrectAnswerPatternInfo }"
           TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }"
           FontFamily="{ StaticResource AppFontFamily }"
           FontSize="16"
           TranslationY="{ OnPlatform iOS=-1, Android=-3 }" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using `HorizontalOptions` on a label exactly?

Comment: What does it look like? Please also show your code instead of explaining it.

Comment: @FreakyAli because i need to center my label. How should i center it in your opinion?

Comment: @Julian i added some screenshots and the stackLayout. I hope this helps to understand the problem

Comment: Use `HorizontalTextAlignment` for this, `HorizontalOptions` are to align the control not the text

Comment: Have you tried setting `HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"` and `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` on the label?

Comment: There is just a slight problem with HorizontalTextAlignment. We have to support arabic language. So we use HorizontalTextAlignment with the property "LayoutDirectionHorizontalTextAlignment" to support "left to right" and "right to left".
Because of this, i tried to center the whole label and not only the text

Comment: @FreakyAli i had a huge misconception. The centered text in arabic is on the same position as in english. So i just solved my problem by setting the orientation to center, when the device identifies as tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Julian and @FreakyAli I found my huge misconception.
I only needed to center the text, when its used on a tablet. The problem I was facing was the combination of centering the text + switch from left to right, when arabic was selected as language.

I just added this part to the code behind:

```cs
public virtual LayoutOptions FeedbackInfoTextAlignment 
{
    get
    {
        if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
            return LayoutOptions.Center;
        return StringTableManager.Instance.IsRtl ? LayoutOptions.End : LayoutOptions.Start;
    }
}
```

This fixed my whole problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).